When is the direct product of two metacyclic groups again metacyclic?
A few minutes ago I saw this: Extensions of metacyclic groups.
"Product of two metacyclic group be metacyclic" is obviously false (as shows the answer in the question). But it mades me curious about something:

When the product of two metacyclic (or two Z-groups) group is metacylic?

We, of course, can take some trivial cases when it occurs (product of two cyclic groups). Probably some other non-trivial examples. I think a direct product (more generally, an extension) of cyclic group with a metacyclic Frobenius group is metacyclic (correct me if I'm wrong). But I cannot find a criterion to ensure when it is or not metacyclic; or even if such criterion exists.

In the finite case: when two metacyclic groups have relatively prime orders, then their direct product is again metacyclic.

@NickyHekster: But that is not necessary, since the direct product of two cyclic groups is metacyclic. I think it's going to be something like "iff you can express $G_1$ as an extension of $C_r$ by $C_s$, and $G_2$ as an extension of $C_m$ by $C_n$, and $\gcd(r,m)=\gcd(s,n)=1$." The cyclic times cyclic case is covered by taking $r=n=1$, for example. I can prove that if $G_1\times G_2$ is finite metacyclic, then there are cyclic $N_i\triangleleft G_i$ with $\gcd(|N_1|,|N_2|)=1$ and $G_i/N_i$ cyclic.

Agree. That is nice. I had not given it a further thought.

This is not a complete answer. In the finite case, I give a sufficient condition, and a necessary condition, but there is a gap between them.
Sufficient condition. Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be finite metacyclic groups. If there exist cyclic groups $N_1\triangleleft G_1$ and $N_2\triangleleft G_2$ such that $\gcd(|N_1|,|N_2|) = \gcd(|G/N_1|,|G/N_2|)=1$, then $G_1\times G_2$ is metacyclic.
Proof. Since $|N_1|$ and $|N_2|$ are relatively prime, then $N_1\times N_2$ is cyclic; it is a normal subgroup of $G_1\times G_2$, and $(G_1\times G_2)/(N_1\times N_2)\cong (G_1/N_1)\times (G_2/N_2)$. Since each of $G_1/N_1$ and $G_2/N_2$ is cyclic, and they are of relatively prime order, then their product is cyclic. Thus, $G_1\times G_2$ is metacyclic.
Necessary condition. Suppose that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are groups such that $G_1\times G_2$ is metacyclic. Then there exist cyclic normal subgroups $N_1\triangleleft G_1$, $N_2\triangleleft G_2$, with $\gcd(|N_1|,|N_2|)=1$, and such that $G_1/N_1$ and $G_2/N_2$ are cyclic.
Proof. Let $M$ be a cyclic normal subgroup of $G_1\times G_2$ such that $(G_1\times G_2)/M$ is cyclic.
Let $N_1$ be the kernel of the map $G_1\hookrightarrow G_1\times G_2\to (G_1\times G_2)/M$ given by $g\mapsto (g,e)\mapsto (g,e)M$. This is isomorphic to the intersection of $M\cap G_1\times\{e\}$, and hence is cyclic. In addition, $G_1/N_1$ embeds into $(G_1\times G_2)/M$, so it is cyclic.
Symmetrically, let $N_2$ be the kernel of the map $G_2\hookrightarrow G_1\times G_2 \to (G_1\times G_2)/M$. Then $N_2$ is cyclic, and $G_2/N_2$ is cyclic.
In addition, $M$ contains the subgroup $N_1\times N_2$; since $M$ is cyclic, then the product $N_1\times N_2$ is cyclic. Since each of $N_1$ and $N_2$ are cyclic, and their product is cyclic, it follows that their order is relatively prime. So we have $\gcd(|N_1|,|N_2|)=1$.
Now, it is not generally the case that the construction in the necessary condition will have the properties of the sufficient one: if $G_1=G_2=C_2$, and $M$ is the subgroup $\{(e,e),(x,x)\}$, then $N_1$ and $N_2$ will be trivial, and $|G_1/N_1|=|G_2/N_2|=2$. Of course, in this case we can pick different normal subgroups so as to get the situation in the sufficient condition (take $N_1=G_1$, $N_2=\{e\}$). So I am not sure if there is a way to tweak the subgroups constructed in the necessary condition to show that the sufficient condition is also necessary.

This is a nice answer! I found a particular result when the groups are Z-metacyclic ($G/G'$ cyclic) that is closely related with your answer.
